# How to remove column attribute by liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I have a column attribute

```
on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

How can I remove it in xml changeset ? Database is mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a refactor operation doesn't exist you can always fall back to a [sql](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html)

```
<changeSet author="me" id="example-001">
    <sql dbms="mysql">ALTER TABLE xxx MODIFY COLUMN yyy ????</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<changeSet id="someId" author="someAuthor" context="someContext">
    <dropColumn tableName="tableName" columnName="columnNameToRemove" />
</changeSet>
```